# Show that a definite integral vanishes for all values of  $a,b,c > 0$.

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

Show $$\int_0^\infty \int_0^\infty \frac{(ax-by) {\rm e}^{-x} {\rm e}^{-y}}{(a^2 x + b^2 y + c x y)^{\frac{3}{2}}} \,dx \,dy = 0$$ for any $a,b,c > 0$.

I came upon the above double integral when simplifying an expression for a probability density function. How can I demonstrate that the integral is zero for any positive constants, $a$, $b$ and $c$?

I've verified the result numerically. At the moment it seems rather fascinating to me that the integral should always be zero given the presence of three free variables, and I would expect there to be a relatively simple derivation.

I've tried all sorts of approaches (integral substitutions including polar coordinates, differentiating under the integral, splitting the domain of integration into pieces) without seeming to make progress.

---

To answer Ali's comment, below I give my crude Matlab code for evaluating the double integral (with the trapezoidal rule) and one output. Regardless of what positive values of $a$,$b$,$c$ I put in, I get something close enough to zero for my liking.

Output of program:

```
double_int = getDoubleInt(2,3,4)

double_int =
            -6.1549e-010
```

Program code:

```
function double_int = getDoubleInt(a,b,c)

x_max = 25;
y_max = 25;
NN_x = 1000;
NN_y = 1000;

x_vec = logspace(log10(x_max/10^10),log10(x_max),NN_x);

y_vec = logspace(log10(y_max/10^10),log10(y_max),NN_y);

XX = x_vec'*ones(1,NN_y);

YY = ones(NN_x,1)*y_vec;

ZZ = (a*XX-b*YY)./(a^2*XX+b^2*YY+c*XX.*YY).^(3/2).*exp(-XX).*exp(-YY);

int_1 = zeros(size(x_vec));

for i = 1:NN_x

int_1(i) = trapz(y_vec,ZZ(i,:));

end

double_int = trapz(x_vec,int_1);
```

Comment: Since MathJax is down: http://1.618034.com/blog_data/math/formula.17081.png

Comment: I'm still incredulous this could be true and haven't yet heard from other numerical tests, but at first glance I think you could interpret it as a function of $a,b,c$ and show it's constant...

Comment: @djws: can yu show us a numerical test of this equality?

Comment: For $a=b$, I believe the result. For $a\neq b$ this looks like a miracle (and I don't believe in miracles).

Comment: @Fabian: I totally agree. Now, I'm doing a few numerical experiments with Mathematica, and so far I get zero for $a=.1$, $b=1$, and values of $c$ ranging from $.01$ to $5$. Every value I've tried gives equality. The caveat is that for some values Mathematica complains that the convergence of the numerical integration is too slow.

Comment: @MartinArgerami: after having done the numerical integration myself, I believe that the statement is correct. As I still don't believe in miracles it should be possible to prove the statement.

Comment: Someone who are authorized to set bounty for this question should set a bounty amount

Comment: While this is no contribution towards solving the problem, it helped me understand that the problem makes sense: for any $a>0$, $b\in\mathbb{R}$, $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{a}{(1+(at+b)^2)^{3/2}}\,dx=2.$$ This is trival to see by substitution. Maybe just some smart substitution is needed for the OP's integral.

Comment: @MartinArgerami Which substitution you have used to get this integral from the original one?

Comment: @Norbert: I started from $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac1{(1+x^2)^{3/2}}\,dx=2,$$ and then I took $x=at+b$ (of course, it should be "$dt$" and not "$dx$" in my previous comment).

Comment: Notice how the square of $ax-by$ is related to the denominator...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The result is surprising because one would think that the combination with the exponentials would be too complicated to make the integral vanish for all $a,b,c$. However, the exponentials don't enter into it because the integral along every line with constant sum $x+y$ is zero, and the exponential factor is constant on these lines. Consider

$$
x=u+v\;,
\\
y=u-v\;,
$$

which, up to a constant factor from the Jacobian, transforms the integral into

$$\int_0^\infty\mathrm du\mathrm e^{-2u}\int_{-u}^u\mathrm dv\frac{a(u+v)-b(u-v)}{\left(a^2(u+v)+b^2(u-v)+c(u^2-v^2)\right)^{3/2}}\;.$$

The inner integral is readily performed; [Wolfram|Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral%20of%20%28%28a%5E2%2bb%5E2%29v%20%2b%20%28a%5E2-b%5E2%29%20u%29/%28a%5E4%28u%2bv%29%2bb%5E4%28u-v%29%2bc%5E2%28u%5E2-v%5E2%29%29%5E%283/2%29%20dv) gives

$$\int_0^\infty\mathrm du\mathrm e^{-2u}\frac2{(a-b)^2+2cu}\left[\frac{a(u+v)+b(u-v)}{\sqrt{a^2(u+v)+b^2(u-v)+c(u^2-v^2)}}\right]_{v=-u}^{v=u}\;,$$

and the result is $0$ since the antiderivative takes the same value at $u$ and $-u$.

Comment: very nice answer, thanks!

Comment: @djws: You're welcome!

Comment: @joriki: +1 (+ bounty) thanks for helping us out ;-)

Comment: @Fabian: My pleasure :-)

Answer (score 8):

Using the substitution
$$
r\frac{1+t}{1-t}=\frac1r\frac{1+s}{1-s}
$$
maps $[-1,1]\mapsto[-1,1]$ and has proven useful in several situations similar to this. Some formulas pertinent to this substitution are
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}t}{1-t^2}=\frac{\mathrm{d}s}{1-s^2}
$$
$$
\frac{r(1+t)+\frac1r(1-t)}{1-t^2}=\frac{\frac1r(1+s)+r(1-s)}{1-s^2}
$$
$$
\frac{r(1+t)-(1-t)}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}=\frac{(1+s)-r(1-s)}{\sqrt{1-s^2}}
$$
Change variables $u=x+y$ and $v=x-y$, then $v=ut$:
$$
\begin{align}
&\int_0^\infty\int_0^\infty\frac{(ax-by)\,\mathrm{e}^{-x}\,\mathrm{e}^{-y}}{(a^2 x + b^2 y + c x y)^{\frac{3}{2}}}\,\mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{d}y\\[6pt]
&=2\int_0^\infty\int_{-u}^u\frac{(a-b)u+(a+b)v}{\left(cu^2-cv^2+2(a^2+b^2)u+2(a^2-b^2)v\right)^{3/2}}\,\mathrm{e}^{-u}\,\mathrm{d}v\,\mathrm{d}u\\[6pt]
&=2\int_0^\infty\int_{-1}^1\frac{(a-b)+(a+b)t}{\left(cu^2(1-t^2)+2u(a^2(1+t)+b^2(1-t))\right)^{3/2}}\,\mathrm{d}t\,\mathrm{e}^{-u}u^2\,\mathrm{d}u\tag{1}
\end{align}
$$
Using the substitution $\frac{a}{b}\frac{1+t}{1-t}=\frac{b}{a}\frac{1+s}{1-s}$ with $(1)$ yields
$$
2\int_0^\infty\int_{-1}^1\frac{(b-a)+(a+b)s}{\left(cu^2(1-s^2)+2u(b^2(1+s)+a^2(1-s))\right)^{3/2}}\,\mathrm{d}s\,\mathrm{e}^{-u}u^2\,\mathrm{d}u
$$
Then substituting $w=-s$ yields
$$
-2\int_0^\infty\int_{-1}^1\frac{(a-b)+(a+b)w}{\left(cu^2(1-s^2)+2u(a^2(1+w)+b^2(1-w))\right)^{3/2}}\,\mathrm{d}w\,\mathrm{e}^{-u}u^2\,\mathrm{d}u\tag{2}
$$
Since $(1)$ and $(2)$ are equal, yet negatives, they are both $0$.

Comment: Oh... my... God...

Comment: I think you got the factors of $2$ wrong. That's why I didn't write them; I knew I'd get them wrong if I did :-) You have $x=(u+v)/2$ and $y=(u-v)/2$, so you should have factors of $1/2$, one from the numerator and one from the Jacobian if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: @joriki: I had originally included more steps, the second line was
$$
\int_0^\infty\int_{-u}^u\frac{(a\frac{u+v}{2}-b\frac{u-v}{2})\,\mathrm{e}^{-u}}{(a^2\frac{u+v}{2} + b^2\frac{u-v}{2} + c\frac{u^2-v^2}{4})^{3/2}}\tfrac12\mathrm{d}v\,\mathrm{d}u
$$
I believe I have it correct.

Comment: Ah, of course, sorry. See, I knew I'd get them wrong ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Take $a=c=1$ and $b$ very small.

Comment: Interesting that for $b>0$ the integral is $0$, but not for $b=0$.